# Categorical column with list value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Dataframe` storing different types of columns, **float/int/object**.

Since, the `Dataset` is too large I am looking for ways to reduce memory usage.

I found `"Categorical"` can be adopted to reduce the memory usage on `"Object"` type columns and I applied this on them. But once I, change a column with list value, error `"TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"`

Here is my dataframe

```
vs_df = pd.DataFrame({'plan_name': ['abc', 'def'], 'plan_id': [10001, 10002]})
vs_df['handled_plans_id'] = np.empty((len(vs_df), 0)).tolist()
vs_df.at[[0, 1], 'handled_plans_id'] = [[105,120], []]
vs_df.handled_plans_id = vs_df.handled_plans_id.astype('category') # Error here

print(vs_df)

     plan_id plan_name handled_plans_id
0    10001       abc       [105, 120]
1    10002       def               []
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1367, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels
```

Any methods solving this or reduce the size of this column with list values are appreciate. Thanks!

**Update**

Lots of values inside `handled_plans_id` column are different. Would like to see any methods to reduce memory usage on this column.

Comment: What if you convert those lists to `tuple`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Tuple uses less memory than list, should be (?).. If convert to tuple, still able to apply "Categorical"?

Comment: I don't know about memory usage. But tuples are hashable whereas lists are not, so at least it shouldn't raise the same exception. If you have mostly distinct tuples then converting to categorical will not help much.

Comment: @BallpointBen Got it, thanks for your help.

Comment: If the tuples will be a known length, you could split them into columns. Categorical should help more then, although not if you have too many distinct numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using tuples.

```
vs_df = pd.DataFrame({'plan_name': ['abc', 'def'], 'plan_id': [10001, 10002]})
vs_df['handled_plans_id'] = [()]*len(vs_df)
vs_df.at[[0, 1], 'handled_plans_id'] = [(105,120), ()]
vs_df.handled_plans_id = vs_df.handled_plans_id.astype('category')
print(vs_df)
```

---

```
   plan_id plan_name handled_plans_id
0    10001       abc       (105, 120)
1    10002       def               ()
```

---

If the tuples will be a known maximum length, you could split them into columns. Categorical should help more then, although not if you have too many distinct numbers. Categorical data is usually [one of a small set--an enumeration](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), like 'heart', 'spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', that sort of thing. If you have too many distinct values, converting to a category won't help much.

---

If the file is too large to fit in memory, [you can chunk it.](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk)